# Admob on Multiple Activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, admob, adview

I have 7 Activities in my application. I wants to **display admob in every activity**

**Whether i have to create each AdView  in every activity?**

or

**is there any alternative to reuse previous activity container** OR **prevent it from destroy** so can i use in next activity....

Any code or hint we'll b appreciate.

Thankx

Comment: Create a super class AdAwareActivity, properly set up/tear down your Ad view in onCreate()/onDestroy(), then in every Activity that requires Ad functions, extends AdAwareActivity.

Comment: I would love to know the answer for this question as I am also trying to figure out the same problem :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I DID this. Thankx to yorkw comment. This is not an efficient code. But you can modify accordingly. That **reduces your code for each activity**.

Just **Extends "TestingAdmobActivity"** & **call SetupAds()** to call your advs.

**My SuperClass "TestingAdmobActivity.java"**

```
package com.test.myadmob;

import com.google.ads.Ad;
import com.google.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class TestingAdmobActivity extends Activity implements AdListener{
    public AdView adView;
    public String ADV_PUB_ID = "a14e2fb60918999";
    private boolean adVisible = true;
    LinearLayout layout;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("Admob", "Calling External");
    }

    public void SetupAds(){ 
    Log.i("AdMob", "Start Setup");
    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.BOTTOM | android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);   //To put AdMob Adv to Bottom of Screen
    Log.i("AdMob", "End Layout Setup");

    addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ADV_PUB_ID);
    adView.setAdListener(this);
    Log.i("AdMob", "Init complete Adview");

    layout.addView(adView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    Log.i("AdMob", "Done AddView Layout");

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();    
    request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    request.addKeyword("LifeOK");

    adView.loadAd(request);

    Log.i("AdMob", "End Setup");    
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler() 
    {
        public void  handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            switch (msg.what)
            {
                case 0:     //Disable Adv
                    if (adVisible)
                        adVisible = false;
                    break;

                case 1:     //Enable Adv
                    if (!adVisible)
                    {
                        Log.i("AdMob", "Case 1");                       
                        adVisible = true;
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:     //Enable but Hide Adv
                        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);                
                    break;

                case 3:     //Enable but Show Adv
                        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void DisableAds()
    {
        Log.i("AdMob", "Request Disable Adv");
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

    public void EnableAds()
    {
        Log.i("AdMob", "Request Enable Adv");
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }

    public void HideAdv()  //Enable Adv but Hide
    {
        Log.i("AdMob", "Request Hide Adv");
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
    }

    public void ShowAdv()  //Show Adv
    {
        Log.i("AdMob", "Request Show Adv");
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("AdMob", "Dismiss Screen");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("AdMob", "failed to receive ad (" + arg1 + ")");    
    }

    @Override
    public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("AdMob", "Leaving Application");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("AdMob", "Present Screen");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("AdMob", "Adv Received");
    }
}
```

**My FirstActivityClass "NewActivity_1.java"**

```
package com.test.myadmob;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class NewActivity_1 extends TestingAdmobActivity {

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i("Admob", "OnCreate");
        SetupAds();
        Log.i("Admob", "Done");

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("Admob", "Going to Activity 2");
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(NewActivity_1.this, NewActivity_2.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**My SecondActivityClass "NewActivity_2.java"**

```
package com.test.myadmob;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class NewActivity_2 extends TestingAdmobActivity {

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i("Admob", "OnCreate");
        SetupAds();
        Log.i("Admob", "Done");

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("Admob", "Going Back to Activity 1");
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**My AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.myadmob"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".NewActivity_1" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TestingAdmobActivity" ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".NewActivity_2" ></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"             
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
             >

        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- AdMob SDK requires Internet permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />              <!-- to get Android Device ID -->   

</manifest>
```

**Note: for the sake of permissions used by google admob sdk, i have to build this on android 4.0 sdk with min-sdk version 7**

Comment: I am a bit confused..How does this reuse the ad container?

Comment: You are reusing the code not ad container. How does this work? While creating Activity_2, you are not reusing the AdView created by Activity_1.

Comment: This solution creates ads which cover content.  Does not appear to shift up UI content, or at least I cannot get it to.

Answer (score 1):

In my app I have a cache of 0..12 ads at any given time. I'm reusing them accross different Fragments in an endless ViewPager. The caching class is in charge of loading the providing the ads to the Fragments.

The trick is to:

1. Call the AdView's `onDestory` only when you're sure you're done with that AdView instance for good. This means that the Fragments themselves are not in charge of this.
2. Passing the AdView's themselves between the Fragments, we need to remember to detach each AdView from its hierarchy:

(only on the UI thread of course):

```
public void detachFromHirerchy() 
{
    View adView = getAdView();
    if ( adView != null )
    {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) adView.getParent();
        if (parent != null) 
        {
            parent.removeView( adView );
        }
    }

}
```