# Admob in the Android application installed

Tags: android, admob

I have an application (**A**) having admob advertising, when pressed a button opens another application already installed in smartphone, for example: **the media player**.

My application (A) is in the background while the media player is open, when closed the media player, is shown again the application (A) with admob advertising.

My question is:

¿How can I do admob advertising, display on the media player?

I have the name of the package media player.

I use this admob code in my application: [Admob on Multiple Activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234762/admob-on-multiple-activities?lq=1)

Comment: If the _Media Player_ application does not belong to you, you **cannot** show / display / superimpose your app's ads in the _Media Player_. Your ads will show up **only** in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do admob advertising, display on the media player?

**AFAIK you Can not do it.** you can only saw admob adds inside your app. As you do not have any command to change anything in another app this thing will not be possible.