# NullObjectReference for Admob in different activities

Tags: android

I had read a few q&a in stackoverflow, but still not able to get it work.
[Admob on Multiple Activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234762/admob-on-multiple-activities)

Similar to above solutions, I got the below error

```
android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

in this line

```
 AdView adView = new AdView(this);
```

Can anyone find out why it happens?

CommonCode.java

```
public class CommonCode extends AppCompatActivity{
//private AdView mAdView;

public void createAdview(){
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CommonCode cc = new CommonCode();
    cc.createAdview();}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You extends `AppCompatActivity` in `CommonCode` that define CommonCode as an Activity.Activity context is null untill it start.
You need to remove `extnds AppCompatActivity` from CommonCode class and pass the context in a parameter as below :

```
public class CommonCode{

    public void createAdview(Context context){
        AdView adView = new AdView(context);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Now in a `MainActivity` you need to call the method like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CommonCode cc = new CommonCode();
        cc.createAdview(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! It works like charm.
Thanks a lot
Just a questions, why do the case from the link extends activity and can still work in his case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass activity context in this line

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
```

Create common class like this

```
public class CommonCode {
public CommonCode (){
}
public void createAdview(Context context){
AdView adView = new AdView(context);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}}
```

And use it like this in your activity

```
CommonCode cc = new CommonCode();
cc.createAdview(this);
```